# UICollectionView unable to scroll through all cells

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using **UICOllectionView**  to make a horizontal scroller. All items are added to the collection view using  `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.but in the runtime i only can scroll to **Read** item which is 4th from the last , the last three items are showing but unable to scroll them . any idea how to solve the issue?

In `viewDidAppear` I have:

```
self.smilyObject =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"None",@"title", self.profilePic ,@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Happy",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"happyL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"In Love",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"inloveL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Confused",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"confusedL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Sad",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"sadL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Beauty",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"beautyL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Surprised",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"surpriseL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Angry",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"angryL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Sleepy",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"sleepyL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Love",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"loveL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Hangover",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"hangoverL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Driving",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"drivingL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Chilling",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"chillingL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Eating",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"eatingL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Workout",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"workoutL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Movie",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"movieL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Insomnia",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"insomiaL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Boozing",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"boozingL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Coding",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"codingL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Coffee",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"coffeeL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Music",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"musicL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Cooking",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"cookingL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Gaming",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"GamingL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Late",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"lateL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Making",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"makingL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Middle",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"middleL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Read",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"readL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Shopping",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ShoppingL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Singing",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"singingL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Smoking",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"smokingL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Stuck In Traffic",@"title",[[UIImage imageNamed:@"trafficL.png"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)],@"image", nil],

                       nil];

    [self.collectionData reloadData];
```

Also I have added :

```
#pragma mark Collection view layout things
// Layout: Set cell size
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"SETTING SIZE FOR ITEM AT INDEX %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    CGSize mElementSize = CGSizeMake(70, 70);
    return mElementSize;
}
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2.0;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2.0;
}

// Layout: Set Edges
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    // return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,8,0,8);  // top, left, bottom, right
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);  // top, left, bottom, right
}
```

Comment: what is the frame of collectionView in viewDidAppear.

Comment: I did not set any frame for the collection view , i have tried it before , but did not work so i removed it . I already have tried by setting frame  
`CGSize(row* rowWidth , collectionviewHeight)`

Comment: i am not asking to set frame of CollectionView.Just check by debugging what is the frame when your view is completely visible,this might show you whats the mistake.

Comment: **width : 505.000000 height : 59.000000 X : 93.000000 Y : 5.000000**

Comment: Width should be <= screen's width. such as for iPhone 4s,5s it is 320pixels. so check your width constraints on collectionView in the xib or storyboard.This is the solution to your problem.